# Python string contains does not work with brackets

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to change the name of venue using contains. Why does the contain not work?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['Table 1 (not in use after 1 Apr 2023)'], 
                   ['wefwfe'],
                   ['eqv']], 
                  columns=['Venue'])

print(df)

df['Venue'].loc[df['Venue'].str.contains('Table 1 (not in use after 1 Apr 2023)')] = 'Table'

print(df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the parentheses, your string is considered a regex (which fails to match), use `regex=False`:

```
df.loc[df['Venue'].str.contains('1 (not in use after 1 Apr 2023)', regex=False),
       'Venue'] = 'Table'
```

Or escape them:

```
df.loc[df['Venue'].str.contains(r'1 \(not in use after 1 Apr 2023\)'),
       'Venue'] = 'Table'
```

Output:

```
    Venue
0   Table
1  wefwfe
2     eqv
```